# Create instances of objects at the push of a button

Tags: c#, winforms, class, oop, instance

[image]

When the button on the panel on the right is pressed I want an instance of an image to be spawned in the blue panel. Im familiar with OOP but new to windows forms and so was not sure on how to create an object and have it instantiated this way. How would I create a parent class that would hold objects like this to be spawned whenever buttons are pressed in windows forms c#?

Comment: What kind of object?

Comment: You could use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) to create a copy of the Object Type, then copy all the properties using `control.GetType().GetProperties(...)` and set them on the new instance. But, should it have Events, too? I think your best option is to have a custom class with a constructor that can take one or more parameters that allows to produce a new object with the pre-defined, required properties/events.

Comment: I added an example (answer) below that uses the DockStyle.Fill for the purpose of showing an image and filling the panel. If you want to add additional controls (objects) in the panel, you'll need to use a different setting such as 'Top, Left, Bottom, etc.", or none at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
class Gates
{
    public Button BtnNOT()
    {
        Button btnNOT = new Button();
        btnNOT.Width = 100;
        btnNOT.Height = 50;
        btnNOT.Text = "some text...";
        btnNOT.Image = some Image...;
        // And what you want

        return btnNOT;
    }

    public Button BtnAND() { ... }
    public Button BtnOR() { ... }
    // And other gates...
}
```

Then when you click on the button in the right panel, this code run:

```
Gates gates = new Gates();
bluePanel.Controls.Add(gates.BtnNOT());
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

in constructor

```
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

in click Event

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control lastPanelContol = null;
        if (panel1.Controls.Count > 0)
            lastPanelContol = panel1.Controls[panel1.Controls.Count - 1];

        var newButton = new Button
        {
            Name = "btnDynamic" + panel1.Controls.Count,
            Text = "btnDynamic" + panel1.Controls.Count,
            Left = 20,
            Width = 100,
            Top = lastPanelContol == null ? 20 : lastPanelContol.Top + lastPanelContol.Height + 20
        };

        panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in showing an image from your system, in the blue panel when you click the button.

This example creates a string array of image names and lets you target the image name to display the image in the blue panel when you click the button.

Assuming your blue panel name is 'panel1', and the panel containing the button is 'panel2', and your button name is 'button1'.

When you click the button, it will show the image you have set in the pics[] array.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowMyImage();
    }

    private void ShowMyImage()
    {
        string[] pics = new string[2];

        pics[0] = "E:\\images\\image0.jpg";
        pics[1] = "E:\\images\\image1.jpg";

        var picbox = new PictureBox();
        picbox.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(@pics[0]);
        picbox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel1.Controls.Add(picbox);

    }
```